# DHCP server for Windows with NTP option

Tags: dhcp, ntp, tcp

Does anybody know about a DHCP server app for Windows 7 Professional 32-bit, with the posibility to configure the NTP server address?

I found these apps:
http://tftpd32.jounin.net/tftpd32.html
http://www.dhcpserver.de/dhcpsrv.htm

Great apps but I can't find any option to add the NTP server address.

Grtz

Answer (score 0):

This one http://alax.info/blog/dhcp-server can be set up to send NTP servers (DCHP Option 4).

[image: Property Page with NTP Option]